Should it be preferred to set UTF-8 charset for HTML in the HTTP headers, in the meta tag, or both?
There are (at least) two well-defined ways to set UTF-8 content encoding for HTML documents served over HTTP.
One is to declare it in the HTTP headers with Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8.
The other is to send Content-Type: text/html as the header (with no explicit encoding declaration) and include a <meta charset=utf-8> tag (or one of the numerous other current/historical ways of spelling that) near the top of the source code (in the first 1024 bytes).
One can also set both (in which case the HTTP header takes priority if a meta tag were to try to declare a different encoding).
Is there an official recommendation as to which of these three options is to be preferred?
Note that I am looking for official information from a standards body, ideally WHATWG, as to which option HTML authors should prefer. Please keep your ‘close as opinion-based’ flags to yourselves. I am also not asking which of two potentially conflicting values a parser should accept (which is already stated above), nor why encoding declarations are needed, nor what the difference is (also already stated within my question). Please keep your ‘opinion-based’ and ‘duplicate’ flags to yourselves. Thank you.

The only possible use for meta tag encoding declaration I can think of is when no HTTP is involved (e.g., double-clicking an HTML file in your desktop). Other than that, it seems to me as relying on magic signatures to identify file contents vs file extensions: it can be a nice additional check, but not the primary source.

The answers in the duplicates do link to official docs, in addition to explaining it in detail. What more do you expect‽
